# Question on windowing and determing connection speed

Tags: ip, tcp, network, transport-protocol, packet-analysis

Hi i'm just learning computer networks and i have learned about windowing in **tcp**

And my question is does we determine connection speed using windowing?

*I mean computer know the number of packets and also the size of each packet*

> So **number of packet * size of packet** in 1 second can be our
>   connection speed right?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So number of packet * size of packet in 1 second can be our connection
>   speed right?

No, that is usually called "throughput."

The connection speed is determined by the clock rate (*i.e.* bandwidth) of the physical circuit.  It's a fixed value based on the hardware and never changes.

Comment: If network connection is fixed value why out internet speed change ?

Comment: Because throughput can change based on network or traffic conditions.